# What do you do with a standard deviation null value?

Tags: clustering, standard-deviation, missing-data

Here's the thing, I was trying a clusterization using some information about the amount of a product. I had something like this:

```
week        amount_sold    price    product
1           1              40       A
2           5              50       A
1           1              40       B
2           0              60       B
.
.
.
```

And I summarised like this:

```
product    mean_price     std_dev_price     mean_amount     std_dev_amount
A          45             7.07              3               2.8
B          50             14.14             1               NULL
.
.
.
```

Of course this is just a simplification, I have more products and more columns. The thing is: how do you deal with this null value? Could I just input zero instead? Can't I use standard deviation column? Should I delete the row of product B? I'm a bit confused here. If anyone could throw some light on it

Comment: You need to inspect the code. It looks as if the mean price for B includes the line with 0 items sold and the mean amount doesn't. Whether that makes sense depends on the goal.

Comment: Are you perhaps using zeros in `amount_sold` to represent no sales, and these are not being included in the SD calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably investigate why you're getting a NULL value there. You probably have non-numerical values for `amount_sold`, maybe a string missed somewhere. A zero value is one thing, but this could be a result of poor pre-processing.